# How to make all PHP echo values go into a HTML Table

Tags: php, html, html-table

How do I fix this issue, you see in the picture below, my code creates a table successfully and echos the first item correctly, but if any other item is added to the cart, it gets displayed below the table, outside the border, not in a row.

**Desired Result:** For 'Sara Lee Muffin' and the quantity, and price (example) to be inside the table in it's own row and remove button. (Basically set out the exact same way a the Toasted Sandwhich, but below it)

My code is below the image.

[image]

```
<body>
        <br>
      <h3>Current shopping cart:</h3>

        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">

        <?php
          //If the cart is not empty, then create a table for the Items
          if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
        ?>

        <tr><th>Item name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th></th></tr>

          <?php
              
        if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
                foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $keys => $values) {
      ?>  
            
     <tr>
       <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $values['item_name'];?></td>
       <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $values['item_quantity'];?></td>
       <td style="text-align:center">$<?php echo $values['item_price']*$values['item_quantity'];?> 
       </td>

        <td><form action="" method="get">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="remove" value="Remove">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $values['item_id']; ?>">
        </form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br>
      <?php
          }
        }
      ?>
        <form action="" method="get">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="payment" value="Confirm">
        </form>
            
        <?php
          }
        else {
          echo "No Items added yet.";
        ?><br>
        <?php
          }
         ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a closing `</table>` inside your foreach loop, so every item in the array prints out a `</table>` tag.

You should add another check for the shopping cart after the loop, and if it exists, print the closing `</table>` tag.